# Custom Feature Generation in OpenNLP Namefinder API

Tags: java, machine-learning, named-entity-recognition, opennlp

I am trying to use the Custom Feature generation of OpenNLP for Named Finder API.

http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html

I went through the documentation but I was not able to understand how to specify the different features.

It just says:

```
AdaptiveFeatureGenerator featureGenerator = new CachedFeatureGenerator(
     new AdaptiveFeatureGenerator[]{
       new WindowFeatureGenerator(new TokenFeatureGenerator(), 2, 2),
       new WindowFeatureGenerator(new TokenClassFeatureGenerator(true), 2, 2),
       new OutcomePriorFeatureGenerator(),
       new PreviousMapFeatureGenerator(),
       new BigramNameFeatureGenerator(),
       new SentenceFeatureGenerator(true, false)
       });
```

But how do you actually use each of these different feature generators to create my own custom features. Can somebody post a sample code defining these feature generators and how do we use it for custom feature generation. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I am also stuck with the same. Were you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

I did not find any documentation either, but for most feature generators the [code](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/util/featuregen/) is quite self explanatory. Here are some links to the source repository:

- [TokenFeatureGenerator](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/util/featuregen/TokenFeatureGenerator.java?view=markup)
- [TokenClassFeatureGenerator](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/util/featuregen/TokenClassFeatureGenerator.java?view=markup)
- [OutcomePriorFeatureGenerator](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/util/featuregen/OutcomePriorFeatureGenerator.java?view=markup)
- [PreviousMapFeatureGenerator](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/util/featuregen/PreviousMapFeatureGenerator.java?view=markup)
- [SentenceFeatureGenerator](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/util/featuregen/SentenceFeatureGenerator.java?view=markup)
- [BigramNameFeatureGenerator](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/util/featuregen/BigramNameFeatureGenerator.java?view=markup)
- [WindowFeatureGenerator](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/util/featuregen/WindowFeatureGenerator.java?view=markup)
- [CachedFeatureGenerator](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/util/featuregen/CachedFeatureGenerator.java?view=markup)

Furthermore, the [documentation](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training.featuregen) you refer to states that the quoted feature generator is **similar** to the default feature generator. However, the [source code](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/opennlp/trunk/opennlp-tools/src/main/java/opennlp/tools/namefind/NameFinderME.java?view=markup) shows that it is actually **identical** to the default feature generator.